# Samba Share is Not Writable From Windows

Tags: centos, samba

I have Samba 3.6.23 on Centos 6.5 and I am trying to get a share to be writeable from Windows 10 machines. I can access the share from Windows but I am not able to write to the share regardless of what changes I make to the permissions.

The folder share is owned by the root user and the group samba. The user accessing the share from Windows is a member of the Samba group.
Folder permission is 755 and g+s

This is the configuration.

```
[SHARENAME]
        comment = Share Name
        path = /usr/share_name/
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
        guest ok = yes
        writeable = yes
        create mask = 0655
        directory mask = 2775
        read only = no
        map archive = yes
        map system = yes
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Change the permissions of `/usr/share_name` to 775.

Comment: Thanks, @ajgringo619, We have tried that. I think it might have something to do with the SELinux context.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with SELinux.